# Alterando rows no DataGridView / Abrindo um form com design diferente

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou com um problema em um projeto escolar, como dito no título, preciso alterar *rows* e abrir um formulário que já tem o seu *design*, mas com coisas diferentes, vamos lá:

O programa é bem simples, um `datagrid`, com Nome, Id, Telefone e uma `checkbox` que define se a pessoa está ativa ou não. Embaixo dele há 4 botões, *Inserir*, *Alterar*, *Deletar* e *Fechar*. O de *Inserir*, **que abre um outro formulário** com `textboxes` para preenchimento dos dados, e 2 botões (Adicionar/Fechar), e *Deletar* já foram feitos.

No botão *Alterar*, eu tenho que **abrir o mesmo formulário do botão Inserir**, **porem o botão de Adicionar tem que estar com outro nome, alterar, e em vez de adicionar uma nova `row`, esta irá apenas alterar os valores dela.** Tentei buscar maneiras de fazer isso, mas até agora nada.

Se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço muito, se não entenderem, estou disposto a entregar as instruções do meu projeto para que vocês entendam melhor. Obrigado!

OBS.: Isso não tem nada a ver com SQL, vários dos resultados que procurei no google no YT tinham a ver com SQL.

Comment: Certo, e qual o problema que você está enfrentando?

Comment: Não tenho ideia de como fazer isso. Sorry, esqueci de botar isso na pergunta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa é usar uma variável de controle para indicar qual comportamento o botão vai ter.

No formulário secundário crie a variável `modo`:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class FormCadastro : Form
    {
        public string modo = "Inserir";

        // ...
```

No evento `Show` do formulário secundário faça:

```
private void formularioCadastro_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Altere "botaoAdicionar" para o nome do botão que você quer 
    this.botaoAdicionar.Text = modo; // Inserir ou Alterar
}
```

No evento `Click` do botão que você quer alterar o comportamento faça:

```
private void botaoAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (modo)
    {
        case "Inserir":
            // Códigos para "inserir" aqui...
            break;
        case "Alterar":
            // Códigos para "alterar" aqui...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

No evento `Click` do botão **Inserir** do formulário principal faça:

```
private void botaoInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FormCadastro formCadastro = new FormCadastro())
    {
        formCadastro.modo = "Inserir";
        formCadastro.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Faça o mesmo no botão **Alterar**, mas altere o modo:

```
private void botaoAlterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FormCadastro formCadastro = new FormCadastro())
    {
        formCadastro.modo = "Alterar";
        formCadastro.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo que o botão fique em "Alterar", primeiro ele estava dizendo que precisava de um construtor que levava 0 argumentos, então eu fiz um, só que, mesmo clicando, ou em inserir, ou em alterar, o botão inserir do formulário secundário fica apenas em inserir.

Comment: Sim, eu sei, eu consegui ontem, mas não consegui editar, mas obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Para isso você vai fazer assim:
Usar o `checkbox` para definir qual `row` você quer alterar;
Criar uma instância do `form` que você está usando para criar um novo registro:

```
var f = new MeuFormCadastro();
```

Depois você vai usar essa variável `f` para preencher os `textbox` do formulário:

```
f.textBoxNome.Text = row.Nome;
f.textBoxTelefone.Text = row.telefone;
```

Depois por fim você irá exibir esse `form` na tela;